# Are All Compound Nouns Countable

Tags: grammaticality, uncountable-nouns, compound-words

Are **all** *Compound Nouns* Countable? for example traffic is an uncountable noun but traffic jam is countable. 
sorry for my mundane question

Answer (score 0):

No, the second noun may be noncountable -- bear baiting, Bieber fever, computer services.

Comment: Thanks, I know that second one can be uncountable, in this situation, I mean if the second one is uncountable is the compound noun countable or not? in this situation should we use this compound noun with "there are" or "there is"

Comment: @FattanehTalebi Which would you use in the examples I gave?  Is Bieber fever annoying or are Bieber fever annoying?